# Can I reasonably expect a USB connection manage a 3.7 Volt 6-8 Watt output at 1.9 Amps or less?

Tags: power-supply, usb

I am thinking about making a 510 Vape eCig mod that runs directly from USB. The cart I would like to attach to the 510 head has a 1.8 ohm resistance atomiser in it and wants to see under 2Amps (or it will burn out). There are lower ohm atomisers that can be used (and higher). The important thing is to hit 6 to 8 Watts (closer to 8 where possible) without crossing the 2Amp mark. The standard battery on these things runs at about 3.7 volts.

Is this something that USB could sensibly be expected to handle? If so what limits should I expect to face?

Comment: The USB output from a typical desktop computer can supply 500mA maximum (and you're supposed to negotiate to get that). That's 2.5W. Since 2.5 < 6, you won't be able to get 6W. Some chargers (eg. Apple iPad) can supply 2A or more, which is 10W. 10 > 8, so they could work.

Comment: But the charged device must enter the high-current mode only after it sees that the chager is shorting the data pins.

Comment: I assume that that's a peak power requirement (only when inhaling?), and that it isn't anywhere close to 100% duty cycle. If so, the *average* power requirement may well be within the 2.5 W capability of a standard USB port, with the peaks supplied by a supercap of some sort.

Comment: If you just don't like relying on batteries while you are surrounded by mains power, the easier solution is making a 12v powered mod with a barrel jack connector for power and a switching (potentially adjustable) voltage/wattage regulator.  Then power it from a wall wart at home or lighter socket adapter in the car.

Comment: You are completely correct @DaveTweed, It is only during use the rest of the time the demand would be close to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the faintest idea what an "510 Vape eCig mod" is (glow plug model car??).

But NO, from you specs this is not something you can expect an USB connection to do for you, because

- An USB host is *not required* to provide more than a minimal amount of current untill the connected slave negotiates for more;
- An USB host is *not required limit* the current that it supplies beyond "keeping it at a safe level", which seems to be interpreted as "when the USB host does not explode it is OK".

This might seem contradictory, but it is the freedom the USB specs allow.

To summarize: The USB host is free to provide either to little or too much current for your purpose.

Comment: A mod is a modified eCig device with a 510 thread connector. (Usually they charge from USB). thank you for helping understand enough not to try something pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the limit on standard USB is 500 mw (1/10 of an amp.) Apple's iPad chargers will put out 2.1 amps after the iPad negotiates for higher than the standard USB power output, but that's a proprietary handshake that only works with Apple-approved USB iPad chargers.

So the short answer is no. You won't get anywhere near 2 amps from a standard USB cable without exceeding the max current you're supposed to draw by a factor of 20x.

Comment: Thank you. I fear I must have seemed very ignorant with my question but you answer has helped.